# Measure of intermittency/continuousness of a signal

Tags: signal-analysis, algorithms, statistics

I have three signals (below) each having the same standard deviation, however, are clearly very different temporally.

[image]

Is there some such metric that could be calculated for each of these signals to give an indication of how they vary over time, such as a measure of continuousness or intermittency if such a metric exists.

If possible, I would like to do this by calculating a single number for each of these signals, rather than windowing into smaller chunks.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any metric measuring the relative importance of high-frequency content vs low-frequency content will be correlated with the amount of abrupt changes in the signal.

You can try spectral roll-off (the frequency under which x% of the energy is concentrated) or [spectral centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_centroid).

Answer (score 1):

I can't come up with any known standard measure, and it all depends on what you exactly need, but one simple measure could be computed like this:

$$M=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}|x_{n+1}-x_n|$$

where $x_n$ is the signal of length $N$. With this measure, the top two functions would be rated similarly (one big change is similar to lots of small changes), and the bottom function would get a considerably larger value (because of its many large changes).